# bat файл для удаления программы на большом кол-ве ПК

Tags: bat

Хочу написать bat файл для удаления определенного софта на большом кол-ве ПК. Удаление производится в два этапа. Сначала останавливаются процессы этого ПО, затем запускается процесс удаления. Оба этапа прекрасно отрабатывают через два bat файла.
Для большого количества ПК написал bat:

---

@for /L %%i in ("list_pc.txt") do (
call program_stop.bat %i% && call program_uninstfll.bat %i%
)

---

В list_pc.txt содержится список ПК для удаления. Одна строка - один компьютер. Через "call" вызываю скрипты. Перебор запускается, но
в консоли получаю ошибку:
Couldn't access :
Указан недопустимый путь.
Судя по всему отрабатывает только первая часть, то есть program_stop.bat и отваливается с ошибкой. До program_uninstall дело даже не доходит.
Подскажите как поправить мой bat.

Comment: Ты пытаешься повторить фунционал gpo/ansible. Рекомендую смотреть в их сторону, потому что, очевидно, это твоя не последняя задача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Синтаксис `for` требует использовать опцию `/F`, указывать имя файла без кавычек и обращаться к переменной через `%%i`

```
@for /F %%i in (list_pc.txt) do ( call program_stop.bat %%i && call program_uninstfll.bat %%i )
```

Comment: Благодарю. В таком виде bat работает корректно. Я собирал файл по советам и примерам со множества сайтов поэтому синтаксис так хромал. Еще раз благодарю. 
Может посоветовать материал где хорошо описан синтаксис bat, желательно с примерами?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/